# Property description must be an object error when my properties are object

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to build a small cart system where the addToCart() function is provided with an id and that id is then used to be one of the key of the cart object.

However, I keep getting an error: `TypeError: Property description must be an object: 2` that happens in the second else. I can't figure out why tho..

```
export function addToCart (id) {
  window.localStorage.getItem('cart');
  if (window.localStorage.getItem('cart') === null) {
    var cart = {};
    Object.defineProperties(cart, {
      [id]: 1,
      writable: true
    });
    window.localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify({ [id]: 1 }));
  } else {
    var cartp = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    if (cartp[id] === undefined) {
      Object.defineProperties(cartp, {
        [id]: 1,
        writable: true
      });
    } else {
      Object.defineProperties(cartp, {
        [id]: cartp[id] + 1,
        writable: true
      });
    }
    window.localStorage.setItem('cart', cartp);
  }
}
```

Comment: try being more explicit cause 1 we dont know what your `window.localStorage.getItem('cart');` returns and 2 try replacing the `[id]` with just `id`

Comment: Craziest use I've seen of `Object.defineProperties` to date. `localStorage` only takes Strings. I would do: `localStorage.cart = JSON.stringify(cartp);` instead of `window.localStorage.setItem('cart', cartp);`.